# Which word to use: Arranging a meeting "between" dates

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I want to ask someone if we could arrange a meeting during some time span *between* two dates, but I'm not sure if "between" is the correct word to use in the context of time, not space. Example phrase:

> "Can we arrange a meeting *between* Monday and Thursday?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Between" works fine. Technically speaking, "between Monday and Thursday" only includes Tuesday and Wednesday. However, that wording is used colloquially to the extent that anyone would understand you to mean Monday through Thursday.

Comment: Or you could say something like "Between Monday and Thursday inclusive", as I've heard before.